# How to change the image in the countdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to get this countdown to show the numbers in the time left in images. GOT IT. I was trying to get it to put said numbers over an image. FINALLY GOT IT. Now I am trying to get the numbers to stop and showing and change the image they are projecting on to change to a 1 day left image. FAILED! I also want it to change the image (in this case to) a Happy Halloween image when the countdown reaches the date it ends. FAILED! One other thing is the countdown needs to change images 1 more time the day after. Here's what I got so far. I have not even come close to getting the images to change.

```js
function getImg(num) {
  var digits = String(num).split(""),
    text = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
    text += '<img alt="' + digits[i] + '" src="https://okoutdoors.com/img/' + digits[i] + '.png"       class="image2"/>';
  }
  return text;
}

CountDownTimer('10/31/2023 10:1 AM', 'countdown');
//  CountDownTimer('02/20/2024 10:1 AM', 'newcountdown');

function CountDownTimer(dt, id) {
  var end = new Date(dt);

  var _second = 1000;
  var _minute = _second * 60;
  var _hour = _minute * 60;
  var _day = _hour * 24;
  var timer;

  function showRemaining() {
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    if (distance < 0) {

      clearInterval(timer);
      document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

      return;
    }
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = getImg(days) + ' '
    /*           + getImg(hours) + 'hrs '     
                 + getImg(minutes) + 'mins '  
                 + getImg(seconds) + 'secs';  */
  }

  timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: yellow;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
}

h1.u-center {
  font-family: serif;
  display: block;
  font-size: 2em;
  margin-top: 0.10em;
  margin-bottom: 0.67em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #254441;
  font-style: italic;
}

hr {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 75%;
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #ff5f04;
}

.parent {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.responsive {
  max-width: 200px;
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
}

.responsive1 {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.imageOne {
  width: 40%;
  transform: translate(74%, 00%);
}

.imageTwo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-40%, -50%);
  width: 13%;
  height: auto;
}

.image2 {
  max-width: 150px;
  width: 40%;
  height: auto;
}

.image3 {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.countdown {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="u-center">Image Countdown</h1>

<hr class="1">

<p align="center">
  <img class="responsive" src="https://www.okoutdoors.com/img/catandmoonr.jpg" alt="Happy">
  <img class="responsive1" src="https://www.okoutdoors.com/img/hallo_spooky.jpg" alt="Happy Halloween">
  <img class="responsive" src="https://www.okoutdoors.com/img/catandmoonl.jpg" alt="Halloween">
</p>

<p align="center">
  <img class="responsive1" src="https://www.okoutdoors.com/img/darkjack.gif" style="width:25%" alt="Spooky">
</p>

<!-- <div id="newcountdown"></div> -->

<div class="container">
  <img class="imageOne" src="https://okoutdoors.com/img/halloween-before.gif">
  <div class="imageTwo" id="countdown"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can see what I got so far at https://www.okoutdoors.com/img/newest_countdown.html

Comment: You should know that there are only certain string formats that are guaranteed to work when passed to `new Date(string)`: See [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2587345/215552) I'm not sure how "10:1 AM" is supposed to be interpreted: 10:01? 10:10?

Answer (score 0):

You could use classes and data attributes rather than hard-coded IDs.

```js
const countdown = document.querySelector('.countdown');

const numberToImgHtml = (n) => n.toString()
  .padStart(2, '0')
  .split('')
  .map(d => `<img alt="${d}" src="https://okoutdoors.com/img/${d}.png" />`)
  .join('');

CountDownTimer(countdown, '2023-10-31T00:00:00Z');

function CountDownTimer(el, targetTimestamp) {
  const endDate = new Date(targetTimestamp);
  
  const daysEl = el.querySelector('[data-unit="days"]');
  const hoursEl = el.querySelector('[data-unit="hours"]');
  const minutesEl = el.querySelector('[data-unit="minutes"]');
  const secondsEl = el.querySelector('[data-unit="seconds"]');

  const _second = 1000;
  const _minute = _second * 60;
  const _hour = _minute * 60;
  const _day = _hour * 24;
  let intervalId;

  function showRemaining() {
    const delta = endDate - new Date();
    if (delta < 0) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      el.innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';
      return;
    }
    const days = Math.floor(delta / _day);
    const hours = Math.floor((delta % _day) / _hour);
    const minutes = Math.floor((delta % _hour) / _minute);
    const seconds = Math.floor((delta % _minute) / _second);
        
    daysEl.innerHTML = numberToImgHtml(days);
    hoursEl.innerHTML = numberToImgHtml(hours);
    minutesEl.innerHTML = numberToImgHtml(minutes);
    secondsEl.innerHTML = numberToImgHtml(seconds);
  }

  showRemaining();
  intervalId = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
}
```

```css
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0 }
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #000;
}

.countdown {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 2rem;
  background-image: url(https://okoutdoors.com/img/halloween-before.gif);
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.unit {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="countdown">
  <div class="unit" data-unit="days"></div>
  <div class="unit" data-unit="hours"></div>
  <div class="unit" data-unit="minutes"></div>
  <div class="unit" data-unit="seconds"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#countdown {
   font-size: 25px;
   text-align: center;
}

if (days > 0) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = getImg(days);

} else {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';
    document.getElementById('imageOne').src = 'day-after-image.jpg';
}
```

This js code add after
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = getImg(days) + ' '

So that its work in if day will be 0 so you have show to expired! And also change img

Chcek the perview
https://codepen.io/yashborda123/pen/dywbKLz

Comment: Okay. I know it's not pretty, but I finally have everything working the way I've been trying to get it to. It works on some platforms, but I can't get it to work on my iPhone. I tried it on an android phone and it worked. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/trino98/4cdm3jqg/6/ to what I have so far.  I appreciate everyone that's helped me get this far. Please help me clean this up and make it work on more platforms. Thank you to anyone who can help in advance and to the one's that's helped so far.